# How to quickly instantiate a pyspark SparkContext for unit testing?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, python-unittest

In my Python 3.8 unit test code, I need to instantiate a SparkContext to test some functions manipulating a [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.html#pyspark.RDD).

The problem is that instantiating a SparkContext takes a few seconds, which is too slow. I'm using this code to instantiate a SparkContext:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

return SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

The tests only run [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.filter.html#pyspark.RDD.filter), [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html#pyspark.RDD.map) and [distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.distinct.html#pyspark.RDD.distinct) on an RDD. In my tests, I only want to test an expected output against obtained output on a tiny dataset (lists of length between 5 and 10) and I want them to run almost instantaneously. I don't need all other features offered by PySpark (such as parallelization).

I tried various ways, such as below, but instantiation takes as much time:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is a few seconds too slow for a test?

Comment: Because since unit tests are executed very frequently, a unit test should run in less than 0.1 seconds. It saves you time at the end of the day. Cf Working effectively with legacy code, from Michael Feathers: https://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052